# Programmatically focus main form of foreground window

Tags: c#, winforms, focus

**EDIT:**
Is it possible to send command to external program (window) to remove focus from control box (RED) to program content (YELLOW)?

[image]

Comment: It is normal that window menu is getting the keyboard focus when the user opens it, so the user can navigate the menu by keyboard. If the menu is closed, focus will automatically return to the control which had the focus when you opened the menu (assuming you don't mess around with the focus otherwise). I guess i don't understand your problem, perhaps rephrase your question to make your problem more understandable.

Comment: Doesn't make much sense.  The main form never likes to get the focus, a control on the form gets it.  That can intentionally be messed with but it merely confuses the user when he can't see which window has the focus.  Leave it up to the user to operate his machine, you don't have to help.

Comment: If that's your problem then there is something funky going on in your software. Whatever you do in your code, or whatever (3rd party) controls you use, you will have to narrow down the scope of your problem and be more specific and informative in your question. Right know you could ask 100 people, and each of them could produce 100 different guesses about what is going on in your code...

Comment: Problem is not in code, that happens with every program on my Windows7... Try to simulate it on your Windows: ALT+SPACE -> 1xECS -> ARROW DOWN -> menu is opened again (instead of, for example, scrolling if you are in browser. And that is the problem, I would like to web page get focus after ESC is pressed).

Comment: @Mgulan, again that is normal behaviour in Window. 1st ESC closes the drop-down, but you are still in the menu (which you would leave by pressing ESC again). This is normal behaviour since decades and any user knows that. Don't try to mess with established UX in Windows, your software will only annoy its users. (Sorry if i didn't pay attention in that you specifically meant to press ESC once)

Comment: What if "Address bar" is focused? There is no way to remove focus from it with with ESC. What key can I use then?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use [WM_SETFOCUS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646283%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) windows message.

Comment: This could work if I could get the "body" (YELLOW) handle.. But, how can I know what is the handle of the window "body"?